# Why can't I use a constant in a php object?

Tags: php, object

Why doesn't this work?

```
define("STR_TEST", "qwerty");

class Test
{
    public $arrTest = array(
        "test"=>"Bla bla bla ".STR_TEST
    );
}

$objTest = new Test();

print($objTest->arrTest["test"]);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can perfectly use constants in class member declarations

```
define('SOME', 12345);

class A {
    public $x = SOME; // works
}

$o = new A;
echo $o->x;
```

The problem is that member declarations do not allow expressions of any kind:

```
class B {
    public $x = 1 + 1; // no
    public $y = foo(); // no
    public $z = CONST . CONST; // no
}
```

Note that this limitation is purely syntactical, that is, the php parser, for whatever reason, simply does not accept expressions there. It's quite possible to have runtime-dependent code in member declarations:

```
define('IP', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

class B {
    public $ip = IP;
}

$o = new B;
echo $o->ip;
```

That is, the documentation quoted above is wrong at this point.

Answer (score 6):

You can only use simple values in a [property declaration](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> [The] declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Especially the concatenation operator is not allowed at that point. If you want to initiate it with a value that is derived from other values, you need to do that in the constructor:

```
class Test {
    public $arrTest;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->arrTest = array(
            "test" => "Bla bla bla ".STR_TEST
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to init the constant in the class itself? Then just do this

```
class Cheese {

    const WHOA = 'me';

    public eat ()
    {
        return Cheese::WHOA; 

    }

}
```